# How to pass through variables through src blocks to other src blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I am using Emacs version 26.3 and Org Mode version 9.3.6.

My goal is to have several different `#+CALL:` lines, each using a different value of some header argument (in the example below, that is `inarg`).

Typing `C-c C-c` on the first `#+CALL:` line below:

```
#+NAME: sub_func1
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :results verbatim :var inarg=""
echo sub_func1 inarg $inarg
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: main_func1
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :results verbatim :var inarg="" :var sub_func1_result=sub_func1(inarg=inarg)
echo main_func1 inarg $inarg sub_func1_result $sub_func1_result
#+END_SRC

#+CALL: main_func1(inarg="hardcoded1")
#+CALL: main_func1(inarg="hardcoded2")
```

produces this error:

```
org-babel-ref-resolve: Reference ‘inarg’ not found in this buffer
```

How do I pass the `inarg` variable all the way down to `sub_func1` without having to hardcode the value of it in both `main_func1` and `sub_func1`?

The results I expect are from the following, which I do NOT want to have to do as it means I have to update both values of "hardcoded1" when that value changes:

```
#+NAME: sub_func2
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :results verbatim :var inarg=""
echo sub_func2 inarg $inarg
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: main_func2
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :results verbatim :var inarg="hardcoded2" :var sub_func2_result=sub_func2(inarg="hardcoded2")
echo main_func2 inarg $inarg sub_func2_result $sub_func2_result
#+END_SRC

#+CALL: main_func2()

#+RESULTS:
: main_func2 inarg hardcoded2 sub_func2_result sub_func2 inarg hardcoded2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can "run an interactive session as an 'inferior process' within
Emacs" using [session-based
evaluation](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html#org068d37d),
and reuse data objects between sharing-session blocks. Here's an
example:

```
#+begin_src sh :session example
inarg="foo"
#+end_src

#+name: main_func1
#+begin_src sh :results verbatim :session example
echo $inarg
#+end_src

#+results: main_func1
: foo

#+CALL: main_func1(inarg="bar")

#+results:
: 
: bar
```